# Rank Math metabox preview for custom field

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes, cmb2

I've created a custom field in Rank Math...

add_action( 'rank_math/vars/register_extra_replacements', function(){
rank_math_register_var_replacement(
'op_shortcode',
[
'name'        => esc_html__( 'OP ACF Field', 'rank-math' ),
'description' => esc_html__( 'Custom ACF field from ACF shortcodes.', 'rank-math' ),
'variable'    => 'op_shortcode(field-name)',
'example'     => esc_html__( 'Chrisad field value', 'rank-math' ),
],
'get_op_shortcode_callback'
);
});
function get_op_shortcode_callback( $shortcodename, $post_id ) {

```
global $post;
    $post_id = "option"; // options page
    $shortcodename = get_field( $shortcodename, $post_id, true );
    return $shortcodename;
```

}

... it works in the frontend but I can't get it to be previewable in the backend metabox.

I wrote to Rank Math and the answer they gave first was, "There’s no additional code to be added to the filter since the custom variable is already working on the front end. For the preview to work, you need to ensure that the current content editor you are working on has WordPress editor support." (Which it does as far as I know because every other Rank Math variable is showing in the preview metabox).

Then they said, "When this happens it means that the custom variable you created contains code that cannot be rendered in the backend because the data is still not yet available." (I don't know what this means.)

And then finally, "The following article explains the default WordPress hooks firing sequence: http://rachievee.com/the-wordpress-hooks-firing-sequence/. Beyond that article, you will have to research further into how to get the variable to load. ACF support/forums might be able to help." (That's a 2015 article on hooks firing sequence which leads me to believe that there is a hook firing out of sequence but I can't figure it out).

I am just looking to see if anyone has any idea how to get the custom field I've registered to show up in the preview metabox in the backend (it is showing in the frontend).

Hope that makes sense.

Any help or insight is appreciated.